# How can it be determined whether a network adapter is wireless?

Tags: java

There are a number of ways to obtain a machine's network adapters & related info such as Sigar & java.net's getNetworkInterfaces(). However, using either of these means, I am unable to determine whether a certain adapter is wireless (unless the name/description explicitly says so).

Are there any ways to determine this through code? (I'd like to be able to do so in both Windows & Linux, but I am willing to deal with system specific solutions).

Comment: After running several tests on several systems, I am finding that the Java code is not very reliable at all. Both through java.net & sigar, I am finding that they often miss some devices on linux altogether. This perhaps to the way linux manages the devices. However, since Linux seems to reliably register wireless adapters as such, by cross-referencing the data in /proc/net/wireless (from Atmocreations' post) and ifconfig, I can determine which adapters are wireless. Windows is still eluding me as I'm avoiding something as complex as sugested by VoidPointer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** *removed the part that is not relevant*

maybe you could use the JNI (java native interface) to call a C-function which gets this flag... with C, this should be possible (though possible that the code would become unportable)

**Edit:** For linux, i found the following. Downloaded the source-code of wireless-tools, including iwconfig. They included library, iwlib.c, simply extracts the names of the interface from /proc/net/wireless or /proc/net/dev

You can get the sources from [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/redhat-fedora-linux-help/108743-iwconfig.html#post530435), this is from Fedora. As the library extracts its data from a path of a standardized file-system, the only thing you need to have is kernel-support for procfs.

Now i can only lead you to the file "iwlib.c", function

```
void iw_enum_devices(int skfd, iw_enum_handler fn, char * args[], int count)
```

i don't know about those parameters, but the source code is commented. Maybe you will have to compare the list you get from java with the one you receive through this JNI-hack...

Guess it's a lot of work for a "little task"; hope you find your way through...

regards

Comment: I mentioned looking at the name/description for an indication the card is wireless. That solution isn't suitable. Also, as I said I don't mind if the solution is system specific - so that would inherently mean that JNI is okay with different solutions for each system).

Now, you mention a C-function that gets this flag - what would that be? I have found no such a thing.

Comment: excuse me, must have read wrong... you're right. i've been looking as well, didn't find anything yet.

if i see some C-function that returns whether an interface is wireless, i will post it. somehow it cannot be too difficult i guess, because iwconfig is able to distinguish, as well. maybe we just got to take a look at that one.

regards

Comment: updated the answer with an approach. removed the points you disagreed with before... regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a platform specific JNI implementation of your functionality, the Windows API function you can use to get a list of wireless network interfaces is *WlanEnumInterfaces* in Wlanapi.h. You'll need to link Wlanapi.lib/.dll. Also, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706716(VS.85).aspx).

I'd recommend that you build a little JNI library with two functions:

```
getWirlessInterfaceCount();
getWirelessInterfaceAddr(int nIf, char *addr);
```

Where you actually make sure the 6 bytes for the address are allocated on the Java side and just filled in on the native side. That way you don't need to worry about memory management on the native side. You can wrap those two JNI calls in a Java method like

```
List<NetworkInterface> getWirelesNetworkInterfaces();
```

.... which calls the two JNI methods, gets the list of all interfaces via the NetworkInterface API and throws out all interfaces whose address was  not returned by the JNI methods.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old, someone may be looking for this solution, so here it goes a simple way to find out in **Windows**.

In the current *NetworkInterface* class the function *getName()* will return unique names that can be things like "eth0", "wlan0" or "net0", always few letters plus a number. 
After gathering the list of NetworkInterfaces and selecting the real ones you can then check if the *getName()* function returns "ethX" for a wired interface or "wlanX" for a wireless interface (X is a number that depends on how many interfaces you have in your computer.)

The following code is an **example** for how you can make this identification, although is necessary firstly to find what interfaces are real, there are many solutions for this.

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class TesteInterfaces {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> tempNetInterface = null;
    try {
        tempNetInterface = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (NetworkInterface iNet : new ArrayList<>(Collections.list(tempNetInterface))) {
        try {
            if (iNet.getHardwareAddress() != null) { //This verification might not 
                                             //be enought to find if a Interface is real.
                System.out.println(iNet.getDisplayName()); 
                if (iNet.getName().contains("wlan")) {
                    System.out.println("It is WIRELESS");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It is NOT WIRELESS");
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}    
}
```

An output:

```
Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 100
It is WIRELESS
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
It is NOT WIRELESS
```